# How to get information about word, address size, address bus size, data bus size and instruction bus size?

Tags: linux, cpu

I was wondering how to get information about the following things from the command line in Linux:

- word (i.e. the size that the CPU can process at one time, which may not be the OS bit-depth),
- address size (i.e. the number of bits in an actual address),
- address bus size (not sure if it is the same as address size by definition, but I think they are different and may not agree),
- data bus size,
- instruction size?

Comment: Many of these are not well-defined (there is more than one bus and they don't all have the same sizes). Even things like “CPU word size” aren't clearly defined, some CPUs (e.g. all PC CPUs) have several word sizes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and look at the results:

```
processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Genuine Intel(R) CPU           U4100  @ 1.30GHz
stepping        : 10
cpu MHz         : 1200.000
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm
bogomips        : 2593.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

A lot of the information that you are looking for can be inferred from this.

Comment: Thanks! (1) About the physical address size, is it possible that it may not be the address bus size? (2) Is it right that  the output doesn't give CPU word?

Comment: @Tim The output gives the CPU word size in a cryptic way: all i386 CPUs can do 8, 16 and 32, and the `lm` flag indicates an amd64 CPU, i.e. the CPU can do 64. The word size for integer arithmetic is the same as for addresses on this CPU family (unless you count segment registers, but that's a whole other story).

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks! (1) What does lm literally mean? (2) What do you mean by "unless you count segment registers"?

Comment: @Tim CPU flag names tend to be obscure and sometimes inaccurate because the flag name was settled before its exact function. Check out the [Linux x86 CPU feature list](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h); `lm` is “long mode”. Segment registers are best left to PC historians (no modern OS uses them); but [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), which raises address sizes to 36 bits on 686 platforms, is supported by most major modern PC OSes.

Comment: `address sizes` is not present on ARM unfortunately.

Comment: @sybreon my current ubuntu(18.04) interestingly does not report the "address size" field !!!!!!

Answer (score 27):

1. `getconf WORD_BIT`
2. `getconf LONG_BIT` (the size of long integers)
3. `arch`

For example, on a Fedora 14 x64 system:

```
% uname -a
Linux grinchy 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 13:07:52 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

% getconf WORD_BIT
32

% getconf LONG_BIT
64

% arch
x86_64
```